# Listener for Python Queue

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, queue

I'm using python queue to insert data packets from mqtt listeners
But
I'm not sure when this queue will be loaded by Mqtt packet.

Can we put a listener on to this Queue ?

note : This listener callback will be used to insert the data in to DataBase.

```
import queue
import time
import threading

print('python queue')



def on_connect():
    print('connected')

# gives message from device
def on_message(client,userdata,msg):
    #print("Topic",msg.topic + "\nMessage:" + str(msg.payload)
    qMqtt.put('msg')
    #replace below line from here and move to listener   
    queueToDB('msg')
   
def queueToDB(msg):
    qMqtt.get(msg)
    dbaseInsert(msg)

def dbaseInsert(data):
    #insert into query
    print("inserted")
       
def run():
    #mqttc= mqtt.Client()
    
    #mqttc.on_connect=on_connect
    #mqttc.on_message=on_message
    
    global qMqtt
    qMqtt = queue.Queue()
    on_connect()
    on_message('client','userdata','msg')

run()
```

Comment: You already have a listener `on_message`, which is the only place where you put something in the queue. I don't understand why you would need a listener on the queue, when you know exactly when you append to it. NB: the indentation of your code makes it impossible to run.

Comment: Queue is being used to reduce the data loss from mqtt on_message.  The process start at on_message will end only after insert of database. ,tried your approach but data we are loosing out

Comment: That is quite vague. If this is the only place where you push data in the queue, then it is also the only time you would need to do something, right? I find this question unclear. Please explain your reasoning why you need yet another listener apart from the one that you are already listening to.

Comment: I think you want some distributed programming. Please consider using something like a Kafka (https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/) or similar distributed Queue. This way, multiple computers can write to the queue, and multiple computers can also consume from it.

Comment: I started looking in to Kafka, Good that you pointed out correctly.  @ssm thanks